# An integral involving the argument of the Gamma function

Tags: calculus, integration, complex-analysis

> Evaluate $$I=\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{t\arg
>  \Gamma(\frac{1}{4}+\frac{it}{2})}{(\frac{1}{4}+t^2)^2}\mathrm{d}t$$
>    where $\Gamma(s)=\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-x}x^{s-1}\mathrm{d}x.$

Note that $I$ converges since $\Gamma(s)\sim s\log s$. I tried Wolfram Alpha, but it hasn't given me an answer after almost 90 minutes of computation,  hence perhaps will never do.

Comment: It seems this question might be better suited for MO, i'll be migrating it there shortly.

Comment: With numerics approximation: `-1.62197`

Comment: For anyone interested, that's the question in MathOverflow: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/318982/an-integral-involving-the-argument-of-the-gamma-function

Comment: @rafa11111, like i clearly stated and everyone has seen, i migrated the question there.

Comment: I just thought it would be useful to inform the link to the question in MathOverflow, so anyone who found your question interesting won't need to search for the question there. Furthermore, you didn't migrate the question (I think only mods can do that but I may be wrong), you only asked the same question there (regarding the "duplication" of questions, take a look in [this meta post](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16288/asking-the-same-question-on-mse-and-mo)).